# How to use bluemix cdn service

Tags: ibm-cloud, cdn

Hi I wanted to use bluemix cdn to store some files such as images.But I was unable to use the service.So can someone help me out how can I use the cdn service.Any details or any help on this is very helpul.Thanks!

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the Bluemix CDN service docs so here is a link to them. They may be helpful to you. https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/cdn/index.html

Comment: @AndrewLohr Thanks.This is my sample app http://node-helloworld-harish8055-1521.mybluemix.net/ .Iam trying to add cdn service,using the documentation provided.In the cdn service domains tab,Iam adding app url...For app url Iam giving http://node-helloworld-harish8055-1521.mybluemix.net/    and for origin route Iam giving mybluemix.net.But it is giving me issue.Showing status as inactive.Also CName is showing as cd.bluemix.net..What is the Cname here.Also can you please help me  what might be the issue and how can I fix this?